# Бесконечный поезд

Tags: java

Представьте себе замкнутую по окружности железную дорогу. По ней едет поезд, последний вагон которого скреплён с первым так, что внутри можно свободно перемещаться между вагонами. Вы оказались в одном случайном вагоне и ваша задача — подсчитать их общее количество. В каждом вагоне можно включать или выключать свет, но начальное положение переключателей случайное и заранее неизвестно.

Все вагоны внутри выглядят строго одинаково, окна закрыты так, что невозможно посмотреть наружу, движение поезда равномерное. Помечать вагоны как-либо, кроме включения или выключения света, нельзя. Количество вагонов конечно (не верьте заголовку).

Предложим один из возможных вариантов решения. Вам нужно включить свет в начальном вагоне, в котором вы находитесь, если он ещё не горит. Затем пойти в одну любую сторону до тех пор, пока не встретите вагон с работающим освещением, при этом обязательно считать пройденные вагоны. Выключаете в найденном вагоне свет и идёте обратно к начальному. Если в нём свет всё ещё горит, то повторяете операцию. Если же нет, значит вы прошли полный круг и знаете ответ.

Для решения этой задачи, я бы хотел организовать LinkedList где последний элемент списка указывает на первый. Это возможно? Можно ли ссылками управлять в LinkedList?

Updated.
Я написал решение.

Comment: В связном списке ссылками, управлять, конечно, можно. Под LinkedList что имеется в виду?

Comment: А вопрос вообще вне конкретного ЯП?

Comment: @Сергей стоит метка [алгоритм], значит главное наглядно показать алгоритм решения. ЯП - вторичен или не важен.

Comment: @Kromster, это если новый участник правильно метку поставил. Если ЯП не важен, тогда почему все вопросы заданы о LinkedList из Java?

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вообще такое моделирование...

Comment: не надо добавлять сюда метку [intellij-idea], вопрос никак не относится к этой ИДЕ.  Используйте эту метку только для вопросов, в которых проблема связана с использованием этой среды разработки. Для общих вопросов по программированию, используйте метки языка программирования, например, [java], [scala].

Comment: @MBo не могли бы вы сказать можно ли связать конец и начало списка ссылками? И если да ,приведите пожалуйста пример, а то сколько гуглил так и не нашел. Под LinkedList имеется ввиду связанный список из java, который реализует интерфейсы deque, list, cloneable

Comment: @Эникейщик хорошо, простите

Comment: @Venoman9867 Если у вас есть доступ к next и prev ссылкам и вы можете их назначать - то да. Но насколько я вижу при поверхностном взгляде на документацию - это всё спрятано внутри, и вам придётся реализовывать связанный список руками

Comment: возьмите любую имплементацию циклического итератора, который,к примеру, есть у гуавы. затолкайте туда любую коллекцию. и все... бегайте по кругу до бесконечности

Comment: @Дмитрий Спасибо большое за подсказку!) Но мне бы хотелось попробовать написать класс, если не справлюсь, обязательно воспользуюсь вашим советом!)

Comment: @Venoman9867 ну смотрите, если вы готовы из коробки достать любую коллекцию , к примеру LinkedList , то почему вы не готовы идти по указанному мной пути? ладно. вы не хотите доставать из коробки циклический итератор, так напишите его сами, в чем проблема? Создаете класс,  инкапсулируете там коллекцию (лучше как раз ArrayList), переопределяете нужные методы, в т.ч. методы, использующие уже имеющиеся у коллекции итератор, только при переопределении делаете его цикличным и все. это позволит вам ходить по кругу

Comment: @Дмитрий Я просто новичок в программировании, мне хочется посмотреть как все из под капота работает и набить шишек) Хорошо попробую сделать циклический итератор, еще раз спасибо большое за помощь!)

Comment: @Venoman9867 да не за что) просто для того, чтобы дать ответ , надо четко понимать задачу. у вас в вопросе не указано, что вы принципиально не используете готовые решения и все, что можно юзать - LinkedList , поэтому и ответ такой.  ведь можно в принципе написать все на массиве (также как это делает под капотом тот же ArrayList) или самому сделать ноды, как у LinkedList... Решений много , они разные, тем более для задач учебных, где главное не результат, а процесс. Посему наиболее быстрый результат - готовый циклический итератор.  Наиболее медленный - реализация все с ноля на основе массива

Comment: @Дмитрий Добрый день! Если вас не затруднит, посмотрите пожалуйста решение.

Comment: ну как по мне, то это слишком сложное решение. вы снова полезли в ноды и при этом еще используете линкедлист, который сам себе инкапсулирует ноды. это странно, как минимум. понимаете, в чем проблема, это решение больше интуитивное, чем инженерное. вы изучили ноду быстренько натянули эти знания на задачу с поездом. это же так классно: можно их по кругу замкнуть. потом ассоциации привели к линкедлисту. ну как же он на нодах! и не важно, что мы ими не управляем и нам все равно свои ноды нужно писать и потом ржавым болтом к линкедлисту их прикручивать. зато все ноды мира собраны воедино)))

Comment: забудьте про инструменты. попробуйте подойти со стороны ооп. дайте ответ на простой вопрос: какие объекты могут существовать для этой задачи? мне кажется, что ответ достаточно очевиден: у нас есть поезд, у нас есть человек, который ходит по поезду (пассажир). поезд содержит определенное количество вагонов, как следствие, поезд. всегда готов сказать. какой там вагон следующий и какой предыдущий и какой освещен. кроме того, поезд имеет "тумблер" включения-выключения света в каждом вагоне.  аналогично с пассажиром. задайте вопрос, что он умеет и что знает. умение - метогды, знания - поля

Comment: @Дмитрий Действительно, такой метод решения очень сильно упрощает разработку. Еще раз спасибо огромное!)

Comment: @Дмитрий Сделал как вы сказали, но что то все равно количество вагонов не совпадает... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    /*Значит, идея такая, что нам нужно включить свет в начальном вагоне, в котором мы находимся, если он ещё не горит.
     Затем пойти в одну любую сторону до тех пор, пока не встретим там вагон с работающим освещением, при этом
     считаем пройденные вагоны. Выключаем в найденном вагоне свет и идём обратно к начальному. Если в нём свет всё ещё
      горит, то повторяем операцию. Если же нет, значит мы прошли полный круг и уже знаем ответ!*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human human=new Human();
        human.countCarriages();
    }

    public static class Train {
        private final Random random = new Random();
        private Carriage head;//это первый поезд
        private Carriage tail;//это последний поезд
        public final int countOfCarriages = random.nextInt(1, 1000);//это сколько в нем будет вагонов
    
        private final ArrayList<Carriage> train = new ArrayList<>();//это наш поезд
    
        //тут мы заполняем поезд с рандомно включенным светом
        public ArrayList<Carriage> makeTrain() {
            for (int i = 0; i < countOfCarriages; i++) {
                train.add(addCarriage(random.nextBoolean()));
            }
            return train;
        }
    
        //метод возвращающий рандомную позицию человека в поезде
        public int randomPosition() {
            return random.nextInt(1,countOfCarriages);
        }
    
        //этот метод нужен для сцепления вагонов, при добавлении нового
        private Carriage addCarriage(boolean value) {
            Carriage newNode = new Carriage(value);
            if (train.size() == 0) {
                head = newNode;
            } else {
                newNode.nextCarriage = head;
                newNode.previousCarriage = tail;
                head.previousCarriage = newNode;
                tail.nextCarriage = newNode;
            }
            tail = newNode;
            return newNode;
        }
    
    }

    public static class Human {
        private final Train train = new Train();
        private final ArrayList<Carriage> randomTrain = train.makeTrain();
        private final Carriage head = randomTrain.get(train.randomPosition());
    
        //метод обхода по вагонам и подсчета их количества
        public void countCarriages() {
            int count = 0;
            boolean end = true;
            //если свет в вагоне выключен мы его включаем
            if (!head.value) {
                head.value = true;
            }
            //Завожу переменную текущий вагон, чтобы итерироваться по поезду
            Carriage currentCarriage = head;
            System.out.println("Сколько вагонов в составе: " + train.countOfCarriages);
            do {
                currentCarriage = currentCarriage.nextCarriage;//текущим вагоном становится следующий вагон
                count++;
                if (currentCarriage.value) {// если свет включен, выключаем его
                    currentCarriage.value = false;
                    for (int i = count; i > 0; i--) {// и идем обратно
                        currentCarriage = currentCarriage.previousCarriage;
                    }
                    if (!currentCarriage.value) {
                        System.out.println("Сколько вагонов насчиталось: " + count);
                        end=false;
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                    }//сбрасываем счетчик
    
                }
            } while (end);//делаем до тех пор, пока голова поезда не выключится
    
        }
    
    }

    //Класс вагон
    public static class Carriage {
        boolean value;//значение света внутри вагона
        Carriage nextCarriage;//переменная которая будет указывать на следующий узел
        Carriage previousCarriage;//переменная которая будет указывать на предыдущий узел
    
        public Carriage(boolean value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.nextCarriage = this;
            this.previousCarriage = this;
    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя. LinkedList это список, и он конечно не может быть зацикленным по смыслу. Вообще, говоря о Java, надо в первую очередь принимать во внимание что классы имеют определенный смысл и способ их использовать "контракт". Язык не позволяет просто это поменять, чтобы ничего не испортить. Если хочется позаимстовать какие-то отдельные детали реализации, то проще всего скопировать код и видоизменить таким образом, чтобы он работал по-новому.

Comment: Действительно, java не позволяет такого, поэтому я решил сделать класс который решит эту проблему, я нашел статью в интернете, как только создам класс, отпишусь!) Вот статья: https://www.baeldung.com/java-circular-linked-list#:~:text=A%20circular%20linked%20list%20is,null%20element%20at%20the%20end.